# Sharepoint 2007 to 2010 Upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I got a Sharepoint project which we developed using 2007 we are in a process of migrating to 2010. We are using database attach approach. I ran pre-upgrade check in 2007 environment it is fine. Then I ran Test-SPContentDatabase didn't come up with any errors. After that I migreated the Wss_Content database using "stsadm -o addcontentdb" no error in the log. the custom solutions we build in 2007 (.wsp) are published to 2010 environment. After migration I can open the site. When I navigate to all site content page I can see all the list. But some list icons are different which we created using list definitions using 2007. All the list are created using list definitions and content types.

When try to open a list it is coming up with error

> Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 33da4de6-739c-4934-a53d-aed0b1767645

Error in log is

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetTokenOfCurrentUser(Boolean bWindowsMode, String bstrLogin, String bstrUserKey, String bstrRoles, UInt32 ulRoleCount)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetTokenOfCurrentUser(Boolean bWindowsMode, String bstrLogin, String bstrUserKey, String bstrRoles, UInt32 ulRoleCount)    50b24177-0a13-4ac0-a8fb-79dc2179506b
05/03/2013 11:01:01.80     w3wp.exe (0x0FA8)                           0x1FB0    SharePoint Foundation             Template Cache                    fo1v    Monitorable    Leaked record detected with address 000000000342D188, name (unknown), and thread local refcount 1. To see AddRef/Release callstacks for this leak, run stsadm -o setproperty -pn refcountcallstacktrackingenabled -pv true.    50b24177-0a13-4ac0-a8fb-79dc2179506b
05/03/2013 11:01:01.80     w3wp.exe (0x0FA8)                           0x1FB0    SharePoint Foundation             Template Cache                    fo1v    Monitorable    Leaked record detected with address 0000000029B68700, name C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Template\Features\RDTMeetingDirectoryList\RDTMeetingDirectory-0, and thread local refcount 1. To see AddRef/Release callstacks for this leak, run stsadm -o setproperty -pn refcountcallstacktrackingenabled -pv true.    50b24177-0a13-4ac0-a8fb-79dc2179506b
05/03/2013 11:01:01.80     w3wp.exe (0x0FA8)                           0x1FB0    SharePoint Foundation             Template Cache                    fo1v    Monitorable    Leaked record detected with address 000000000342DB48, name (unknown), and thread local refcount 1. To see AddRef/Release callstacks for this leak, run stsadm -o setproperty -pn refcountcallstacktrackingenabled -pv true.    50b24177-0a13-4ac0-a8fb-79dc2179506b
```

Comment: Check anser of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178952/attempted-to-use-an-object-that-has-ceased-to-exist-exception-from-hresult-0x

Answer (score 1):

Did you rebuild the solutions (.wsps) for SharePoint 2010? Or is there a 2010 version available? Sounds to me like something in there doesn't play nicely with SharePoint 2010.